# How do i add foreign key to existing table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to add a foreign key to the table STUDENTS from the table PROGRAMS

```
ALTER TABLE COLLEGE.dbo.STUDENTS  
        ADD FOREIGN KEY(ProgramId) REFERENCES 
        PROGRAMS(ProgramId);
```

But it giving the following error :

> Foreign key 'ProgramId' references invalid column 'ProgramId' in referencing table 'STUDENTS'

Not sure what i am doing wrong here any tip or solution would be a great help.

Comment: You need to define the column before you can use it for a foreign key reference.

Comment: That SQL is correct, the error is telling you the problem. There's no column `ProgramId` in the table `STUDENTS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column needs to exist in the table before it can be used for a foreign key reference.  So I assume you intend something like:

```
ALTER TABLE COLLEGE.dbo.STUDENTS  
        ADD ProgramId INT;  -- have to guess at the type

ALTER TABLE COLLEGE.dbo.STUDENTS  
        ADD FOREIGN KEY (ProgramId) REFERENCES 
        PROGRAMS(ProgramId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to add *a column* with a related foreign key.

In SQL Server, you can do this in a single commad, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE COLLEGE.dbo.STUDENTS
    ADD ProgramId INTEGER
    CONSTRAINT StudentsProgramIdFk FOREIGN KEY(ProgramId) REFERENCES PROGRAMS(ProgramId);
```

You should adjust the datatype of the column to your exact need. The key point is that the new column *must* have the same datatype as the column it references (that is `PROGRAMS(ProgramId)`).